# Showing map type switcher on google maps

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

On the recently updated google maps there is now a Satellite / Map switcher in the bottom left that allows a user to switch between the two. But it also shows a preview of what the map would look like.

When I am using the Google Maps API, how do I enable this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot enable the little map preview in Google Maps JS API v3. You have only limited control over `MapTypeControl`. When creating a new map, you can adjust controls, disable them, etc:

```
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
      center: position,
      zoom: zoom,
      mapTypeControl:true,
      mapTypeControlOptions:{
          mapTypeIds:[google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP, google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN],
          position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_TOP,
          style: google.maps.MapTypeControlStyle.DEFAULT
      } 
  });
```

But you cannot set it to display the little preview. If you set `MapTypeControlStyle` to `DEFAULT` according to [docs](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#MapTypeControlStyle), what you will see on the map depends on map size and other factors, so it's possible on some maps on some platforms you will see some preview, but it's not guaranteed:

> When the DEFAULT control is shown, it will vary according to window
>   size and other factors. The DEFAULT control may change in future
>   versions of the API.

The other two options, `DROPDOWN` and `HORIZONTAL_BAR` is probably not what you are looking for.

Nevertheless, if you really want to display the little previews, just disable the default controls (`mapTypeControl: false`) and create your own Map Type Controls. Example on how to create your own controls is [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/control-custom). You will just create your own preview button using js/css/html and when user clicks it you will just set new map style: `map.setMapTypeId(mapTypeId:MapTypeId)`. Since the button is your own creation, you have full control over it, you can control the preview icon, add hover effects, anything..